# Color accuracy problems rendering PDFs to image using Core Graphics on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, colors, core-graphics

I have been having problems with rendering certain PDFs to images using the Core Graphics PDF functions on iOS.  Specifically, I am using the `UIImage+PDF` category provided by this library: https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF.  The relevant methods are:

From "UIImage+PDF.m"

```
+(UIImage *)imageWithPDFData:(NSData *)data atSize:(CGSize)size atPage:(NSUInteger)page
{
    if(data == nil || CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeZero) || page == 0)
        return nil;

    UIImage *pdfImage = nil;

    CGFloat screenScale = [self screenScale];
    NSString *cacheFilename = [ self cacheFilenameForData:data atSize:size atScaleFactor:[self screenScale] atPage:page ];

    if(_shouldCacheOnDisk && [[ NSFileManager defaultManager ] fileExistsAtPath:cacheFilename ])
    {
        pdfImage = [ UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:cacheFilename ] CGImage ] scale:[self screenScale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp ];
    }
    else
    {
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width * screenScale, size.height * screenScale, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, screenScale, screenScale);

        [PDFView renderIntoContext:ctx url:nil data:data size:size page:page];
        CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
        pdfImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image scale:screenScale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

        CGImageRelease(image);
        CGContextRelease(ctx);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        if(_shouldCacheOnDisk && cacheFilename)
        {
            [ UIImagePNGRepresentation( pdfImage ) writeToFile:cacheFilename atomically:NO ];
        }
    }

    return pdfImage;
}
```

and from "PDFView.m"

```
+(void)renderIntoContext:(CGContextRef)ctx url:(NSURL *)resourceURL data:(NSData *)resourceData size:(CGSize)size page:(NSUInteger)page
{
    if ( resourceURL || resourceData )
    {
        /*
         * Reference: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/
         */
        CGPDFDocumentRef pdf;

        if( resourceURL )
        {
            pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL( (__bridge CFURLRef) resourceURL );
        }
        else
        {
            CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)resourceData);
            pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
            CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        }

        CGPDFPageRef page1 = CGPDFDocumentGetPage( pdf, page );

        CGRect mediaRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect( page1, kCGPDFCropBox );
        CGContextScaleCTM( ctx, size.width / mediaRect.size.width, size.height / mediaRect.size.height );
        CGContextTranslateCTM( ctx, -mediaRect.origin.x, -mediaRect.origin.y );

        CGContextDrawPDFPage( ctx, page1 );
        CGPDFDocumentRelease( pdf );

    }
}
```

The results that I am getting are a mixed bag.  Many PDFs appear to render correctly.  However, some have some serious color accuracy problems.  Here is an example of the original:

[image: Original Image]

And the bad render:

[image: Bad Render Image]

As you can see, the problem is mostly in the green channel in RGB (Cyan in CMYK?).  So my hypothesis is that it's a color space/color profile issue with the PDFs that render poorly.  A bit of searching lead me to this SO with a similar problem: [pdf images color space trouble ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840961/pdf-images-color-space-trouble-ios/).  The author notes that he traced his issue to a lack of color profile in the PDFs and his solution was to ask his designers to embed the color profile.  I don't know how to verify if this is the problem for me, and the solution may not be viable for me because I don't have access to the original files or original designers.

If anyone could provide guidance as to how I might be able to process these PDFs in code to correct the color issues (e.g. adding a color profile, using a different color space, etc.) or how I may be able to pre-process the PDFs on a computer before rendering on the iOS device, I would appreciate it!

Comment: We'd really need to see an example PDF file in order to determine what the problem is. In my opinion its 'most likely' to be caused by CMYK->RGB conversion, and unlikely to be resolved by adding an OutputIntent colour profile. Though converting the colour space to ICCBased might work. Hard to say without knowing what's in the file.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback @KenS.  If it helps at all, I put a sample PDF up here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18408411/sample.pdf

Comment: Had a quick look, it 'looks like' the colours are all specified in CMYK, including the Separatio9n colour which has a CMYK tint transform. The specified method (in the PDF Reference) of converting CMYK->RGB is quite crude and I believe this is what is causing your problem. You don't say what image format you are rendering to, if you can render to a CMYK image then it should be OK. Otherwise, if you need to render to RGB, you are either going to have to get the PDF with RGB colours, or use something better to do the rendering. Have you considered Ghostscript or MuPDF (there are other solutions)

Comment: Thank you very much, @KenS.  The UIImage+PDF library that I am using renders to a CGBitmapContext (in-memory bitmap format) using a RGB color space.  Please correct me if I am wrong, but I am under the impression that this is the only viable option using CoreGraphics on iOS to render a PDF.  I have not looked at other libraries to do the rendering yet as it seems like this will complicate the process significantly, but as you so, it may be one of my only options.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I know absolutely nothing about iOS :-( I would be amazed if it accepted anything other thsan RGB though :-) If you are going to accept PDF files in arbitrary formats, and colour fidelity is important to you, then I think you will have to use a different library.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with PDFs exported from Adobe Illustrator.

I was able to resolve it by changing the color profile included by Illustrator during export.

By default it uses "Working CMYK", changing this to "Generic RGB Profile" resolves the issue.

If you have a copy of Illustrator, you should be able to open the existing PDF file you have, and "Save as..." with the correct profile information.

Before:
[image: Before Image] 
After:

[image: After Image]

Settings Used for correct rendering:
[image]